# Introduction to CAML in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, scripting, caml

I am new to SharePoint development and i just saw a scripting. It was about retrieving list data using CAML and CSOM. 
I somehow understood the scripting but i cant write a script on my own. Can someone tell me how should i start with this? I just need a direction on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Below guidelines should helpful.

[CSOM CRUD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

[CAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema)

Comment: Thanks Lee. It was a great help.